# mongodb aggregation doesn't show group field data

Tags: mongodb, group-by

My database sample:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "50c97f4f6e46e4b31634934"
    },
    "index": "6633333",
    "uniq_name": "com.test.fix",
    "ad": "com.ad",
    "ad_delay_time": "43200000",
    "track_time": {
        "$date": "2012-12-13T07:10:06.056Z"
    }
}
```

my database is in million and when i tried a query on this data:

```
db.track.aggregate( [ 
{ $match: { track_time: { $gte: ISODate("2012-12-18T00:00:00.000Z") }}},
{ $group: { _id: { ads:  "$ad" },
            count: { $sum: 1} } }
])
```

it doesn't show me different ad's name instead it shows count of a digit number which is not in ad, in actual which is ad_delay_time. It shows me all values for ad_delay_time shows as

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : {
            "ads" : "43200000"
        },
        "count" : 2187735
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

I don't know why it query like this. Also i have to query data for single day, so should i used **$gte** or direct mentioned date stamp. Please help me on this query

Comment: I have noticed that your doc, of course will not be picked up by that query but I am taking that doc as an example. Are you sure that `ad` does not for some reason equal that value for those docs? That query should work just fine.

Comment: instead if i put another field in place of **ad** like **uniq_name** then it working fine and give me exact result

Comment: Sure sounds like you have docs with `ads: "43200000"` in your collection.  Have you checked with `db.track.find({ads: "43200000"})`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK: yes there are some entries, but it doesn't group ads , it shows only single ads entry.

Comment: Then that's why you're seeing that result in your `aggregate`.  Wasn't that your question?

Comment: @JohnnyHK: but i have to get all ads names, there is only count of single field

Comment: I assume that's because that's the only ad with `track_time >= "2012-12-18T00:00:00.000Z"`.

Comment: @shihon: Did you run the query @Sammaye suggested? That should show exactly what is entering the group step of the aggregation query. Alternatively, you could just run the pipeline with `$group`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a wrong function in my php, because of this i am getting all entries of ad_delay_time in ads and ads entries in ad_delay_time. That was my noob mistake which i had seen after running query: **db.track.find({ad: "43200000", track_time: { $gte: ISODate("2012-12-18T00:00:00.000Z") }}).count()**. I really apologize for this.